# Template specialization with cv and ref types

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

In order to understand metaprogramming I created a simple example:

```
template <class T> struct add_cref      { typedef T const& type; };
// template <class T> struct add_cref<T&>   { typedef T const& type; };


std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << std::is_same<add_cref<int>::type, int const&>::value << std::endl
    << std::is_same<add_cref<int&>::type, int const&>::value << std::endl
    << std::is_same<add_cref<const int>::type, int const&>::value << std::endl
    << std::is_same<add_cref<int const&>::type, int const&>::value << std::endl;
```

The result is: **true, false, true, true**
When I uncomment the template spec, the result is as expected (all true)

My question is, why is the second one false and the last one true without the specialization when both use the specialization when uncommented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T> 
struct add_cref { 
    typedef T const& type; 
};
```

With the type `add_cref<int&>::type`, `T = int&`. The type `add_cref<int&>::type` is then roughly the same as `int& const &`, which means that the reference `int&` is const and not the integer itself.

Edit: With the type `add_cref<const int&>::type`, `T = const int&`. The type `add_cref<const int&>::type` is then roughly the same as `const int& const &`, which means that the reference itself `const int&` is const (the second const is ignored by the compiler) but it refers to a `const int`. This means that `add_cref<const int&>::type` must be `const int&`, even without specialization.

With specialization:

```
template <class T> 
struct add_cref<T&> { 
   typedef T const& type; 
};
```

For `add_cref<int&>` since in this specialization `T&=int&` then `T=int`. 
As a result, the `type` of `T const&` becomes `int const &`.

Comment: Why is the last one true then? shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: @Quest no. The specialization is about `T&` and for `int&` this means T=int, so `T const&` becomes `int const&`

Comment: I still don't get why ist the last case true even without specialization

Comment: @Quest I misunderstood your previous comment. The last one is true because the type of the referenced value was `const int` to begin with. Making the reference itself const (rather than the referenced value) is already ignored by the compiler, and reference to reference is also ignored and treated as a simple ref. Since the referenced type is originally const int, then the reference should also be of type `const int&`